# Ways to say 'You needn't apologize'

Tags: word-choice, words, politeness

How would one politely assure another that there is no need to apologize? For formal use I think it might be 謝られる必要はありません; does this sound good?

For more casual use, could you say いえ like when you respond to thanks?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

How about...

> - (いえいえ、) 謝っていただくことはありません(よ)。
> - (いえいえ、) 謝っていただくことではありません(よ)。
> - (いえいえ、) 謝っていただかなくていいんです(よ)。
> - (いえいえ、) 謝っていただくことなんか(何も)ありません(よ)。
> - (いや、/ いやいや、/ううん、etc.) 謝らなくていい(んだ)よ。 -- casual
> - (いや、/ いやいや、/ううん、etc.) 謝ることないよ。 -- casual
> - (いや、/ いやいや、/ううん、etc.) 謝ることなんか(何も)ないよ。 -- casual